# Android studio Requirements

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android programming and going to start with android studio as an IDE. The question is: does android studio with whole packages include everything it needs to work with?

Comment: Yes ! It does include just everything !You will need JDK 64 bit !

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Android, simple downloading Android Studio from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) that includes IDE, platform tools, platform and emulator system image with Google APIs will be enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

Per Requirements -Java Development Kit (JDK) 7 or above

It include all thins you want for Android development.

It comes preconfigured with an optimized emulator image and all the API's you needed installation is easy process and updates give you new versions..

Answer (score 1):

Answer is Yes.

Android studio contains all packages include everything it needs to work with.But you have to install jdk first in order to install android studio.

Comment: Anything else needed?

Comment: Nope :)  nothing else

Comment: I just have an old version of that. After installation it forces me to update sdk to version 5, I have 4.4 and it won't start til completing update

Comment: You should always go with the update :) latest version obviously contain the updated parts. inverse for the old version